# Why i can't catch this Exception?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception, xamlparseexception, xamlreader

Why I can't catch the following `XamlParseException`?

[image]

After I click the *Continue* button the program continues with a normal behavior (an Exception is catched and the `ex.Message` is printed on the console).

The problem is the Visual Studio exception dialog. Why it appears?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have break on ALL exceptions turned on in debugging most likely. Take a look at "Exceptions..." (Ctrl+Alt+E) under the Debug menu, see if the "CLR Exceptions" has Thrown ticked. If so then you might want to untick it.

When enabled this means that even thrown exceptions that are normally caught (first chance exceptions) will be caught by the debugger.